# Calculate Diameter of Cylinder w/ 4 Distance Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $4$ variables that each provide a distance measurement in a straight line from $4$ equally spaced reference points to $4$ points on the surface of a cylinder (essentially graphing points on the cylinder), is there a formula to plug in each distance and determine the diameter of the cylinder (whether or not the three-dimensional plane of the reference points are level or plumb to the cylinder)?

[image: Simple Depiction]
[image]

Comment: Nope, you need 4 parameters to specify the axis of cylinder and 1 parameter for the radius, you need either 5 points or 4 points + 1 extra constraint on orientation of cylinder.

Comment: Thank you for the response Achilles Hui. 

Would it work to add the additional point to the center? 

Can you please provide the formula for using (5) points or direct me to a reference where I can learn more about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As @achillehui mentioned in their comment above, $4$ points are not enough to specify the cylinder, you need $5$ or more points.

In my solution below, I will assume that you picked $5$ points $\{ \mathbf{r}_i\}, i=1,2,3,4,5 $ on the surface of the cylinder.

The equation of the most general circular cylinder is

$ (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_0} )^T (I - \mathbf{a a}^T ) (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_0}) = R^2 $

where $\mathbf{r} = [x, y, z]^T $, and $\mathbf{r_0} = [x_0, y_0, z_0]^T $ is **any** point on the axis of the cylinder.  The unit vector $\mathbf{a}$ points along the axis the cylinder, and $R$ is the radius of its cross section.

Expanding the equation, we get

$ \mathbf{r}^T (I - \mathbf{a a}^T ) \mathbf{r} - 2 \mathbf{r}^T (I - \mathbf{a a}^T) \mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{r_0}^T (I - \mathbf{a a^T} ) \mathbf{r_0} = R^2 $

Let $\mathbf{u_1}$ and $\mathbf{u_2}$ are two unit vectors that make up together with $\mathbf{a}$ an orthonormal set. Then we can take

$ \mathbf{r_0} = c_1 \mathbf{u_1} + c_2 \mathbf{u_2} $

Substituting this, the equation of the cylinder reduces to,

$ \mathbf{r}^T (I - \mathbf{a a}^T ) \mathbf{r} - 2 \mathbf{r}^T (c_1 \mathbf{u_1} + c_2 \mathbf{u_2}) + c_1^2 + c_2^2 - R^2 = 0 $

Now the unit vector $\mathbf{a}$ is parameterized in spherical coordinates as follows

$ \mathbf{a} = [ \sin t \cos s , \sin t \sin s, \cos t ]^T $

Corresponding to this, we can assign $\mathbf{u_1}$ and $\mathbf{u_2}$ as follows

$ \mathbf{u_1} = [\cos t \cos s, \cos t \sin s, - \sin t ]^T $

$\mathbf{u_2} = [-\sin s, \cos s , 0 ]^T $

Now the parameter vector for the cylinder is

$ \theta = [ t, s, c_1, c_2, R ]^T $

And for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ we will have $5$ different scalar functions of these $5$ parameters.

Using the Newton-Raphson multivariate method, and a good initial guess of the parameters, the method will converge to a solution within a few iterations.
Given the complexity of the equation, one can replace the exact analytical computation of the Jacobian with an approximate numerical computation based on a small (e.g. $0.01$) step in the value of the parameters.

The above describes the method to use for a cylinder whose axis has a unknown direction.  If, however the direction of the axis is known, then the problem becomes much simpler.  Looking at the equation of the cylinder from above

$ \mathbf{r}^T (I - \mathbf{a a}^T ) \mathbf{r} - 2 \mathbf{r}^T (c_1 \mathbf{u_1} + c_2 \mathbf{u_2}) + c_1^2 + c_2^2 - R^2 = 0 $

If $\mathbf{a}$ is known then $(I - \mathbf{aa}^T)$ is a fixed known matrix, and $\mathbf{u_1}$ and $\mathbf{u_2} $ are fixed and known vectors.  This reduces the unknowns from $5$ to only $3$ which are $c_1$ , $c_2$ and $R$.  So only $3$ points are needed.  Define

$ c_3= c_1^2 + c_2^2 - R^2 $

Then the cylinder equation becomes

$ \mathbf{r}^T (I - \mathbf{a a}^T ) \mathbf{r} - 2 \mathbf{r}^T (c_1 \mathbf{u_1} + c_2 \mathbf{u_2}) + c_3 = 0 $

Substitute $\mathbf{r_1}$, you get

$ - 2 \mathbf{r_1}^T (c_1 \mathbf{u_1} + c_2 \mathbf{u_2}) + c_3 =  -\mathbf{r_1}^T (I - \mathbf{a a}^T ) \mathbf{r_1} $

which is linear in $c_1, c_2, c_3$.  Using $\mathbf{r_2}$ and $\mathbf{r_3}$ we obtain 2 more equations, and the whole system of the $3$ equations can be solved easily for $c_1, c_2,c_3 $.  Finally

$ R^2 = c_1^2 + c_2^2 - c_3 $

Comment: Thank you Hosam Hajjir. I assume 5 coordinates are required when the coordinates are in random points on the cylinder, so does it provide any benefit (or reduce the amount of coordinates required) by having the source instrument that measures distance to be equally spaced (as shown in the rough sketch I provided)? Does that not provide reference amongst the points and thereby confine them into a fixed sized grid? For example, if the coordinates of the source instrument is: A (1,1); B (1,0); C (0,0); D (0,1); and aligned to the cylinder with a laser, wouldn’t it provide a reference x, y, or z?

Comment: It would, but you have to find the coordinates of the points on the cylinder surface, as follows, for example, $\mathbf{r}_1 = \mathbf{A}+ s_1 \mathbf{d} $ where $\mathbf{A}$ is the coordinate on the source instrument, $s_1$ is the distance to the cylinder, and $\mathbf{d}$ is the unit direction vector along the ray from the instrument to the cylinder.

Comment: Please check my updated solution that covers the case when the axis of the cylinder is known.